# How does Stack Overflow avoid questions that are not in English?

Tags: discussion, english

I've listened to every Stack Overflow / Stack Exchange podcast that I can recall, and I'm aware that there was a conscious decision to make Stack Overflow (at least initially) an English-only programming question site. I'm also aware they've now expanded to have a [Portuguese site](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions), etc.

I'm OK with this decision (in fact I think it was a wise decision), and I personally have no desire to alter this however... I'm ***curious*** how (and or if) this is actually enforced?

Answer (score 23, accepted):

Through community moderation.

We flag anything in a foreign language as off-topic. Or some kind soul translates the post to English, one or the other.

Comment: I'm guessing the volume must be fairly low then as I've never come across any that I can recall.

Comment: Indeed, it doesn't happen all that often.

Comment: @scunliffe If it happens, the question is usually down- and closevoted very quickly. Unless you browse by newest questions and refresh often, the chances of seeing a non-english question are probably close to zero...

Comment: Well, consensus seems to be that translation is fraught with peril, of questionable worth due to the OP being unable to use english, and generally making community moderation difficult... it's certainly a radical change of about the same order as simply replacing the post with your own. See http://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262014/how-to-deal-with-non-english-posts too.