# Dealing with non-English posts in Low Quality Queue

Tags: discussion, review-queues, low-quality-posts, english

I'm aware of [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262014/how-to-deal-with-non-english-posts/262054#262054) and request (expressed there) to flag non-English post for moderator attention.

However, should I do anything extra, when non-English post pops up in Low Quality (or any other) queue -- how should I react? I can't use `Edit` (I don't speak in such language) and of course, I can't click `Looks OK`. Should I `Skip` it or use `Recommend close > Unclear what you're asking`?

Comment: You should vote to *delete* the post.

Comment: Why systematically delete a potentially valuable question that may be translated by the op?

Comment: @Keysharpener How do you know it could be valuable? It could be spam. The only non-English post I can recall seeing was most likely spam, based on what Google translate showed.

Answer (score 16, accepted):

You can flag it for closure (recommend close) as *Unclear what you're asking*. It is unclear because it's not in our language.

If it's an answer, then recommend deletion. <s>I wouldn't bother with a comment; the OP probably wouldn't understand anyways.</s>

You might as well leave a comment saying that non-English posts aren't allowed. Even if the OP doesn't understand, other readers might learn something.

Comment: and downvote for not reading the rules before posting

Comment: comment could be helpful to explain other readers about what's wrong with the post

Comment: @vba4all You can't downvote from the VLQQ.

Comment: @gnat I think most people can see what's wrong with it. ;)

Comment: @Scimonster in my experience, such an assumption turned wrong so frequently that I made a habit to add comments to explain 200% evident things :)

Comment: "non-English posts aren't allowed"... to be clear, posts without English aren't allowed.  It is allowed to have a foreign language **in addition to** English.

Comment: @vba4all Really downvote?  If they couldn't write their question in English, do you really expect them to be able to make it through the rules?

Comment: @Dropped.on.Caprica Google Translator would probably be enough so any other user reading the question could fix the grammar... That's probably as minimal effort required as we can ask for..