# Non-English question mis-flagged during review - suggestions for improvement?

Tags: discussion, review-queues, flags, declined-flags

I recently reviewed [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30041552/chamar-um-metodo-do-bean-do-jsf-dentro-do-javascrip) and I voted to close it because it is not written in English. As an option "not in English" is not available, I chose a different one:

The post is probably not "rude or abusive", but I felt that the second-level heading "A reasonable person would find this content inappropriate for respectful discourse" would apply, (because it is not written in this site's language) so I chose that option.

A little later, my flag was declined:

> a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it

I know that being in the wrong language is not "offensive". However I have read the pages ["be nice"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/be-nice) and ["help center"](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic) linked in the selection box, and the other choices, e.g. "off-topic", didn't seem more appropriate to me.

1. I guess my first question, **What would have been my recommended course of action?** has been anwered already: [How to deal with non-English posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262014/how-to-deal-with-non-english-posts) (and others). I could have translated that question or flagged as "in need of moderator attention".
2. I'm wondering how this little mishap looked from the flag reviewer's perspective. **Did the moderator have any other reasonable choice but declining my flag?** Isn't there something like a "modify" button for incorrect, but rightful flags, similar to suggested edits that can be modified? Could the moderator have interpreted my flag as being rude towards that non-English speaking poster?
3. **Would it be a good idea to mention Non-English questions somewhere
   in the flagging dialog or linked media?**

Comment: Please take heed: While the OP and some others prefer translation, consensus is that that's a *bad idea*, and the highest-voted answer explains why.

Answer (score 24):

1. You should have voted to closed the question as "unclear".
2. No, declining the flag was exactly the right course of action.  You flagged it incorrectly, and as a result, your flag was declined.  Non-English text is not sufficient inappropriate as to be considered offensive or abusive.  It's inappropriate, but in a very different way.
3. You can find plenty of information on the topic on meta if you're really interested, I don't see this as a sufficiently common problem to merit something as extreme as wasting extremely valuable space on the flagging dialog for a special case like this.  That real estate too valuable.