# Is there a recent change of the way on how we flag non-English content with low quality?

Tags: discussion, declined-flags, low-quality-posts

One of my recent low-quality flags on [non-English content](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74988061/compte-gratuit-pass%c3%a9-%c3%a0-un-compte-payant-sans-consentement) is declined. The reason given is:

> Use Needs Improvement > Needs Details or Clarity flags instead for non-English questions. https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680

Interestingly, the provided link is the reason why I have been consistently flagging non-English content as low-quality, as mentioned inside the link:

> Questions not written in English should be closed/flagged as "Needs more details or clarity" or close voters can use the following custom close reason: "I'm voting to close this question because it is not English."

This is the first time that I have had such a flagging being declined. At the time happening, I am wondering if there is any policy change on how we handle the non-English content in 2023. Is flagging as low-quality no longer works for non-English content anymore?

Comment: "_I have been consistently flagging_" you have enough reputation to cast close votes why are you flagging those? (Unless you are talking about answers that are not in English)

Comment: @AbdulAzizBarkat Actually, I do both closing and flagging for most of the time. I have like thousands of flags for such case marked as helpful so I thought it was ok to keep flagging them. Am I misunderstanding something?

Comment: AFAIK, VLQ flags also go to the mod review queue, while this is not something that needs mod intervention. The flags marked helpful (automatically) seem to be a side-effect of the question getting closed, whether with or without mod intervention.

Comment: If you've cast a close vote you shouldn't also be flagging it (unless it is for a separate issue). You might notice now that you have the close votes privilege your flag options have decreased since they are now present in the close vote options. When you cast a close vote the question goes to the review queues and is handled by other normal users. VLQ flags also go to the moderators as Andrew T. mentions.

Comment: Related: [Am I misusing the "Very Low Quality" flag?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/265573/am-i-misusing-the-very-low-quality-flag)

Comment: Hold on. Moderators will **decline** flags when they *agree that action should be taken*, because the wrong flagging reason was used? What is the purpose of such bureaucracy? (Aside from that: surely I'm not the only one who finds the way that flags interact with close votes *really confusing*?)

Comment: @KarlKnechtel No, you're not; I've been using this site for over a decade and I don't remember half the time. I've been of the opinion for a while now that having multiple flag and close reasons is a waste of everyone's time; there should just be one "flag", for situations where content needs to be nuked ASAP because it very obviously violates the site rules; and one "close", for when content *may* violate said rules. Essentially "flag" would go immediately to mods and "close" to a queue.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I agree with you. Sometimes I've even clicked the wrong radio button by mistake, and the moderator declined my flag because it was the wrong reason. :(

Comment: @KarlKnechtel I think we should be a bit more compassionate towards the mods. There aren't many of them, and incorrectly flagging a post creates more work for them (even if the post should be deleted, just for a different reason).

Comment: Still not sure why there is not a close option and points them to es, pt, ru, etc.

Answer (score 44, accepted):

I'm the moderator who declined the flag.

My rationale was as follows:

- The [existing guidance](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680) indicates:

  > Questions not written in English should be closed/flagged as "Needs more details or clarity" or close voters can use the following custom close reason: "I'm voting to close this question because it is not English."
- The post already had a close vote on it, which was already moving the post towards being in the correct state (closed).
- To me VLQ means that the post warrants immediate removal. In general, I'd prefer to allow the asker the opportunity to improve their question (as would be done for every other close reason). (I acknowledge that this is my own personal stance, and not a policy or otherwise "official" stance)
- It doesn't necessarily require moderator intervention, the community can handle the post all the way through deletion.

---

Having said that, if I had to do it over again, I would probably have marked the flags as helpful with the note I included in the decline message.

I acknowledge that VLQ is **not** an *incorrect* flag, it's just a longer route to the post being handled (especially if that's the only flag on the post). While it may be *preferable* to flag with the standard reasons, upon reflection (and some conversation) I agree that the flag had good intention and shouldn't have been declined.

So while VLQ flags are not *necessary* on non-English questions, they probably shouldn't be *declined* either, and I will adjust accordingly.

Comment: Poking [this one](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/422034) - When are we moving forward with the site-specific close reason for non-English questions? That'd solve this kind of flagging problem for once and for all.

Comment: It wouldn't have solved this problem, @iBug, because a user could still flag the post as VLQ instead of voting to close. Still, we all pretty much think adding that close reason is a good idea. Today (January 3) is the first day that anything could possibly be done about it, as that's the first day that staff is back from holiday vacation. I presume once they have a chance to settle in, Henry or another one of us will discuss it with a CM and make sure they're on-board.

Comment: @CodyGray Wait it's December 3 today? What am I missing?

Comment: You're missing the ability to read my mind, @iBug. What I meant to type (and have now corrected that comment to say) is *January*. Time is all an illusion anyway, though, right? :-)

Comment: [Lunch time doubly so.](https://dl.acm.org/doi/abs/10.1145/2857274.2878574)

Answer (score 25):

There has not been any policy change. What there has been is [two new moderators](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/421619) minted.

A bit of background: [The "very low quality" flag is universally panned because it's not clear how it should be used](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/357344). In practice, some mods (like me) take a very liberal, broad approach to handling VLQ flags on questions, validating such flags as long as it is immediately obvious that (and how) the question should be closed. Other mods are far more restrictive in their willingness to validate VLQ flags on questions, preferring instead that you raise a more specific flag type that precisely indicates the problems with the question—or even preferring that you leave handling the problem entirely to the community, without involving a moderator, by using close votes and/or downvotes.

While there are certainly merits to both points of view, and I could argue convincingly for either (as I did in the above-linked answer), most of the arguments against a "liberal" handling of VLQ flags on questions come down to either (A) system-level objections (i.e., this type of flag shouldn't exist at all), or (B) moderator-workload concerns. I firmly believe that, even though both are true and valid objections, neither of these are the flagger's fault or concern, and thus should not be reasons to decline a flag.

Anyway, the compromise position—perhaps the one that all moderators would agree with, and thus the one situation in which you are "safe" using the VLQ flag—is to interpret the VLQ flag as requesting immediate deletion. In this view, the VLQ flag means something akin to: "While not irredeemably rude or abusive [for, if it were, I'd be raising a 'rude/abusive' flag], this post is inherently/fundamentally problematic and needs to be immediately deleted by a moderator."

Unfortunately, even the application of this interpretation brings us to a difference of opinion: does non-English content need to be immediately deleted? I thought this would have been an obvious "yes", but in discussing this privately with the moderator who declined your flag, I discovered that that is *not* a universally-held point of view. The moderator involved thought it was reasonable to simply close non-English questions, allowing them to be re-written in English. On that basis, and consistent with [the policy they linked](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680), your flag was declined because you should have voted to close the question (the exact closure reason isn't all that important), not raised a VLQ flag on it.

(The linked policy is clear on this; that I cannot argue with. I do object to declining flags on the basis of violating nitpicky guidance when they conform to common sense, and I also object to having a different view of the VLQ flag when it comes to answers as compared to questions, because I think that's just confusing and silly.)

Although I have [convinced Henry not to decline such flags outright in the future](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/422476), it's nearly impossible to guarantee that [all 28 moderators](https://stackoverflow.com/users?tab=moderators) interpret and handle flags in exactly the same way.

What I *will* do is attempt to reassure you that raising a VLQ flag on non-English content is not a crazy idea, and that having a flag declined due to a difference of opinion is not a big deal.

Going forward, I think it is reasonable that you handle non-English questions by voting to close them (even though I, personally, think it is *equally* reasonable to raise VLQ flags on them). If nothing else, [this is "the course of least resistance"](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/336723). The good news is that [we are planning to add a close reason specifically for non-English content](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/422034). Hopefully, that'll make it more clear and more obvious what to do in situations like this.

Comment: Non-english questions should be immediately deleted to prevent other people from editing it and to protect users from potentially rude or spam content.

Comment: Just for those of us who specialize in answers, the same flag procedure is consistent as usual, yes? *Answers should be deleted*, correct? Also, I disagree with the idea of leaving closed non-English questions around cluttering the site. We have enough clutter with the English questions that are never revisited by the author or anyone else ever again. What a confusing mess that invites!

Comment: The guidance that Henry was following, namely [this FAQ](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680), specifically says that answers should be flagged as VLQ, @ouflak, so that should not be an issue. But, yes, agreed entirely with you and Dharman's points. These are among the many reasons to delete non-English content immediately.

Comment: "I discovered that that is not a universally-held point of view" Meta has as far as I remember hosted a battle between the crap huggers and the crap deleters. Crap huggers want to hug crap, polish it and put it on pedestal for the world to see. Crap deleters want to delete the crap. And so the crap huggers try to create as many artifical obstacles as possible to stop the crap deleters from deleting their precious crap, whereas the crap deleters try to find ways to delete the crap as swiftly and effortlessly as possible.

Comment: *"I do object to declining flags on the basis of violating nitpicky guidance when they conform to common sense"* - if a mod decides they disagree with me that action is needed on a flag I raise and so doesn't take the action I was expecting they'd take, I would *like* them to decline the flag, even if they think I have a valid perspective and was behaving reasonably by raising it. That gives me a nudge to look at the post again and perhaps notice something I missed or gain some wisdom from considering the mod's point of view, or else perhaps take some followup action.

Answer (score 18):

I believe the linked guidance should be updated to not just allow, but *encourage* VLQ flags on non-English content for the simple reason that non-English content is completely unsalvageable and should be removed ASAP. Why ASAP?

Because the large number of "helpful" editors who apparently exist only to farm rep and never read guidance are likely to find such content and "helpfully" attempt to edit it into shape, only compounding the problem.

Comment: "completely unsalvageable"  would indicate that it is inherently nonsense. non-English content is trivially salvageable by translating to English. Though only the person that posted it should be doing that

Comment: @MartinSmith If the person who posted that content didn't want it to be deleted, **they should have posted it in English to begin with**. Those are the site's rules. We do not need an exception to those rules for the hypothetical case that said person later decides to come back and translate that content, which I am willing to wager almost never happens.

Answer (score 15):

Situations like these are getting tiresome. While it is true that you shouldn't needlessly use flags when you have enough rep to close vote, in order to reduce moderator workload, there is no policy saying that correctly cast flags should be declined for that reason.

The attitude of "you categorized this piece of garbage as the wrong kind of garbage, so it will not be handled" is harmful for the site. Garbage should be removed, it shouldn't matter if you happened to put stinky garbage in the non-stinky garbage bin, it's still garbage.

As for the VLQ queue/flags, it does *not* mean "needs immediate removal", it never did. The only thing that needs immediate/urgent removal is spam. Very low quality means, [as per actual site policies](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts):

> very low quality (i.e. no amount of editing can salvage the post)

This is true from non-English questions. No amount of editing by others can save the post. Waiting around for someone who happens to know the language and then translate it is going way too far. This isn't some charity organisation where we are sworn to take care of even homeless kitten given to us. If people can't even gather an utter minimum of reality awareness in order to realize that the language used on the Internet is English, it is *their* problem. We have no obligation to teach communication skills or (wait for them) to translate their garbage question. This site is about programming, it is not kindergarten.

Everyone should just close/delete garbage when you encounter it, end of story.

Comment: `The attitude of "you categorized this piece of garbage as the wrong kind of garbage, so it will not be handled" is harmful for the site.` This, a million times this! The time for treating every user submission as if it is a special snowflake is long past, but too many curators still seem to reject this reality.

Answer (score 3):

> Interestingly, the provided link is the reason why I have been consistently flagging non-English content as low-quality

The link says to flag as "Needs more details or clarity", not to flag as "Very low quality". There was not a (recent) change in policy, only a change in enforcement. (I will refrain from calling the change good or bad. The relevant point is that it happened.) You misread the advice, but no one was concerned enough to call you on it before (but also see the note at the end of this answer).

> Questions not written in English should be closed/flagged as "Needs more details or clarity"

In this context, "closed/flagged" should be read as "closed OR flagged", not "closed and flagged". In fact, "closed and flagged" is not possible, since the ability to flag as "Needs more details or clarity" disappears when you gain the ability to vote to close as "Needs more details or clarity". That is, the awkward, long form of the advice is:

> Questions not written in English should be closed as "Needs more details or clarity" OR flagged as "Needs more details or clarity" [whichever you are capable of]

So when you chose a different flag reason, you were not quite following what this says. (That is not intended as a criticism. Joining two words with a slash introduces ambiguity, so misreading is understandable.)

---

It might be worth noting that there was a change – or at least a cleanup – about 10 months ago. A mod deleted several answers to the linked question, some of which recommended flagging as "Very low quality". Perhaps you had visited that page before the cleanup? If you did, maybe you had taken your flag reason from the now-deleted answers. If that's the case, misreading "closed/flagged" to match your pre-existing knowledge is even more understandable. So maybe the answer to your question is that, no, there was no change in 2023, but there was a subtle change early in 2022.

On the other hand, I believe the mod who did the deletions does not object to your use of "Very low quality" flags, so my guess is that the change early in 2022 was more a change in tidiness than a change in policy. Still, it might have helped set the stage for the current situation.

Comment: FWIW: I did the cleanup because the question is a [[meta-tag:faq]], and our convention is that FAQs only have 1 answer, marked as community wiki so everyone can edit it. Having a bunch of different answers, with varying opinions, can be very misleading/confusing, so it isn't very useful in a canonical FAQ that we (and others) often refer people to. My intent in deleting those other answers was *not* to change any meaning or policy. As you surmised, I did/do think VLQ flags are valid on this type of content. I didn't notice that the answer was explicitly avoiding recommending them.

Answer (score -10):

Is content in a language other than English garbage? 
I would say no. It is badly placed, that is, it should be in the forum of the corresponding language. 
Or it should be translated into English by the author (online translators make it easy). 
Warn the author of such behavior and give him/her the opportunity to make corrections would be appropriate. In case said author does not do so, the option is to close the question temporarily, and delete it after a certain time.
(Can such deletion be automated?)

A question or answer can be very valuable despite being poorly posed or written in another language.
Reformatting or reasking it would be a valuable option. 
I think in Spanish, I speak in Spanish and I write in Spanish, but I publish here in English thanks to the web. 
I think that is the right thing to do.

Comment: Try to enter a shop somewhere else in the world, lets say in the middle of the Mongolian steppe. Then persistently insist on speaking Spanish with the store clerk. What do you think their opinion of the quality of the things you are saying is? Will they consider you to be arrogant and rude? Do they have any obligation to keep you around in their store while you ramble on in Spanish?

Comment: *online translators make it easy* - Online translators often make a mess of technical terminology in programming questions.  I would not recommend using one blindly, without understanding the English it outputs and at least checking that those are the right English names for the programming concepts you're asking about.  So that's not really "easy" anymore, it takes work.  (Unless you do already know enough English to check the translation easily.)

Comment: @Lundin I've been a travel agent and I've only seen so much arrogance in one country. Usually everywhere people try to communicate.

Comment: "Usually everywhere people try to communicate." In English, indeed. Particularly so when visiting a country where English is the native language. It doesn't need to be flawless but you are at least expected to make the attempt.

Comment: @PeterCordes If the translators are not perfect, but that does not mean that such translation is incorrect. That is why I say that not only the wording but the context has to be considered. The names of variables e.g. are accepted by regulations that are unicode.

Comment: @Lundin Not true, I have seen many American tourists try to communicate in other languages when they travel. Only the very ... They pretend they are special and everyone should communicate with them in their language.

Comment: @Lundin Yes and that we usually do the programmers who visit this site, but the comments made go in the opposite direction, this site is exclusive for people who speak perfect English, and that saddens me.

Comment: @peter-mortensen How do I thank someone for their help in correcting my question/answer? Or is that wrong to bring it in?

Comment: @ManuelRosendoCastroIglesias: Stack Overflow is for people who are able to communicate in English on the Internet, by whatever means work well enough for them to actually be understood well enough, including perhaps machine translation.  If questions or answers are understandable enough, and interesting enough to be worth the effort, more fluent users may edit to improve them.  If not (either because they're simply uninteresting or because they're *not* comprehensible enough), they'll get downvotes.  There are versions of Stack Overflow in some of the world's other major languages.

Comment: It sucks that different languages are a barrier to communication sometimes, but historically the main solution to the problem for a certain subject-matter has been to use a certain lingua franca that everyone has to learn.  e.g. Latin was used that way by scholars long after it wasn't anyone's native language.  In chess and math, English and Russian have been major languages.  These days, English is the most common choice for communication about computing, so unless two people share a common language and want to communicate in it, English is the go-to.  And the choice for SO's archive of Q&As.

Comment: *Warn the author of such behavior and give him/her the opportunity to make corrections would be appropriate.* - That's exactly what "closed as non-English" would do, as a custom close reason or the upcoming addition to the menu.  If a poster does translate their question, it can get reopened.

Comment: @PeterCordes It is what I say in my answer, you should be given the opportunity to improve or correct said question/answer. This is the largest programming community, with the highest number of questions. Non-English speakers deserve to be evaluated, at least, for their effort in communicating.
Negative flags should indicate poor code quality or question/answer, and not just wording.

Comment: Questions shouldn't be answered unless/until they're in English.  Stack Overflow has chosen English as its lingua franca; its archives of useful Q&As for future readers to search shouldn't be cluttered with non-English ones that the typical reader won't understand.  Closing (not deleting) is exactly what we should be doing for questions that can't or shouldn't be answered in their current state.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/250864/discussion-between-manuel-rosendo-castro-iglesias-and-peter-cordes).

Comment: *Non-English speakers deserve to be evaluated, at least, for their effort in communicating.* - Yes, in terms of their ability and effort to communicate *in English*.  Nobody's saying we should close questions for not being in *good enough* English (unless they're truly not comprehensible), just that questions fully written in French (which I can somewhat read but the average SO user can't at all) for example are not on-topic.

Comment: (@Manuel Rosendo Castro Iglesias: You thank you by trying to *learn* from it. And perhaps pay it forward by contributing to the copy editing effort on Stack Overflow, now or in the future. Remember to fix ***everything*** in a post (to the best of your ability—leave it if you are unsure).)