# Should I edit to add translation of error details written in non-English language if I know the meaning?

Tags: discussion, questions, english

When looking for list of questions in [c#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/c%23), I have found [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/40260410/invalidoperationexception-when-soap-webservice-but-working-on-dev-machine) which explains error message written in German like this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: Die ?????????????????????????????????????????.?????????????????????????????????????????-Methode kann nicht reflektiert werden.

---> System.InvalidOperationException: Fehler beim Reflektieren von ''.
---> System.InvalidOperationException: Das XML-Attribut '' im Namespace 'https://www.yyy/xxx/' ist bereits im aktuellen Bereich vorhanden. Verwenden Sie XML-Attribute, um einen anderen XML-Namen oder -Namespace für das Element anzugeben.

bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.AddUniqueAccessor(INameScope scope, Accessor accessor)
bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.AddUniqueAccessor(MemberMapping member, INameScope elements, INameScope attributes, Boolean isSequence)
bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)

--- Ende der internen Ausnahmestapelüberwachung ---
bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter)
bei System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(String elementName, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, XmlMappingAccess access)
bei System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, Boolean serviceDefaultIsEncoded, Boolean rpc, SoapBindingUse use, SoapParameterStyle paramStyle, String elementName, String elementNamespace, Boolean nsIsDefault, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean validate, Boolean openModel, String key, Boolean writeAccess)
bei System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ReflectMethod(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, Boolean client, XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, String defaultNs)
```

I know that the message may be translated to English as this:

```
System.InvalidOperationException: The ?????????????????????????????????????????.????????????????????????????????????????? method can not be reflected. 

---> System.InvalidOperationException: There was an error reflecting ''. 

---> System.InvalidOperationException: The XML attribute '' from namespace 'https://www.yyy/xxx/' is already present in the current scope. Use XML attributes to specify another XML name or namespace for the element.

at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.AddUniqueAccessor(INameScope scope, Accessor accessor) 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.AddUniqueAccessor(MemberMapping member, INameScope elements, INameScope attributes, Boolean isSequence) 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) 

--- End of inner exception stack trace ---

at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionMember[] xmlReflectionMembers, String ns, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, RecursionLimiter limiter) 
at System.Xml.Serialization.XmlReflectionImporter.ImportMembersMapping(String elementName, String ns, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean hasWrapperElement, Boolean rpc, Boolean openModel, XmlMappingAccess access) 
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ImportMembersMapping(XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, Boolean serviceDefaultIsEncoded, Boolean rpc, SoapBindingUse use, SoapParameterStyle paramStyle, String elementName, String elementNamespace, Boolean nsIsDefault, XmlReflectionMember[] members, Boolean validate, Boolean openModel, String key, Boolean writeAccess) 
at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapReflector.ReflectMethod(LogicalMethodInfo methodInfo, Boolean client, XmlReflectionImporter xmlImporter, SoapReflectionImporter soapImporter, String defaultNs)
```

The main question:

Should I edit the question myself with translated error information to inform readers, leave OP translate it to English on his own or call for someone with German as his/her native language to help with more proper translation?

I had read [this question](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262014/how-to-deal-with-non-english-posts) too, however in this case the problem statement(s) provided in English, with error message and stack trace information written in German.

Comment: I say translate _if you can_, and leave a comment explaining your actions to the OP. And optionally you could point them to [Spanish Stack Overflow](http://es.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: sorry, I forgot you said _german_ not _spanish_.

Comment: Uh-oh, you just created a question that's going to be googled by *thousands* of German users in the next decade.  They'll want a solution, not a translation.  At least add a link to the Q+A.  Do consider that, after editing, you'd likely to have just created a duplicate.  All and all, maybe translating it isn't such a good idea :)

Comment: After some deep thinking, I solved this by adding a comment preferring OP to translate it himself without performing edit on my side and giving short explanation for those who don't know German.

Comment: The linked question is not actually the right answer IMO. The question's body is actually in perfect English, it is just the content quoted from the machine