# The posts which are not in English

Tags: support, declined-flags

I have flagged a question which was not in English. And it has been declined giving me the following message:

> Using standard flags helps us prioritize problems and resolve them
>   faster. Please familiarize yourself with the list of standard flags:
>   see [What is Flagging](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/flag-posts)?

Yet for the questions [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content) and also [here](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262014/how-to-deal-with-non-english-posts), the most voted answers are suggesting to flag it. I sent the flag of **'Moderator Intervention'** writing the note 'The post is not in English' and it got rejected. May I ask you the reason? Can Stackoverflow team clarify the rejection of my flag please?

Thanks.

My post is clearly asking: IF these questions which you guys are flagging as duplicate SUGGEST that I have to flag(above all the second link), WHY did my flag got rejected?

Comment: Use the *low quality* flag. There is no need for a custom flag here. Flagging it for one of the review queues will get it deleted without any need for moderator invention which is probably why it got declined. The message you were given already explains this.

Comment: You should be more clear as to why this isn't a duplicate instead of just asserting it.

Comment: @ivarni Thanks. I didn't think it was suitable because some posts can in fact be salvageable, also the link barely takes in consideration the posts in other languages.

Comment: @HeikkiMäenpää If you read my whole post, I think you will get the idea. My post is clearly asking: IF these questions which you guys are flagging as duplicate SUGGEST that I have to flag, WHY did my flag got rejected

Comment: You seem to be basing your truth on the second link you added which indeed has a highly upvoted post recommending to flag for moderator **attention**. I think that is a tiny bit misleading and led you to flag for moderator **intervention**. I have the idea that the answer you refer to still intends you to pick any of the usual flag options and not get the Stack Overflow moderators involved. (we're all moderators, really)

Comment: the way how to flag in this case is described in duplicate: "Questions written in non-English should be closed as _unclear what you're asking_" - this is the action you should have picked in flag dialog instead of making custom flag

Comment: @Gimby Exactly Gimby, thank you.

Comment: @gnat Why then on the second link there is a post with more than 100 votes suggesting the moderator intervention ?

Comment: @Redfx Good point, it does not require a custom moderator flag. "very low quality" or "unclear what you're asking" will suffice. The accepted answer there, written by me years ago, is also wrong - translating a post is not the best thing to do. (I'll see if I can get that answer deleted).

Comment: because over 3 years ago when this answer was written (and a year before that second question was closed as a duplicate of an official [meta-tag:faq] guidance) this looked like a good idea to many readers

Comment: "WHY did my flag got rejected?" I thought it would be obvious by now that you picked the wrong flag...

Comment: @Gimby yup it is clear, i had to edit because it was suggesting me to; because it was 'unclear' that it was not a dup. I would not want to delete the post in case there are other users having the same prob.. Reading that 100+ voted post on that link, and getting rejected. I can delete the post without any problem

Comment: @Redfx FYI. I addressed the answerer over there. They [updated the answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/posts/262054/revisions) so it is now clear which flags to use. You did the right thing to flag, and to check what flag to use - you were just misled about what flag to use. With the update of the answer, future visitors will no longer suffer the same confusion.