# How do I deal with non-English *links*?

Tags: discussion, edits, english

My question revolves around answers posted in English referencing sources in [another language](https://developer.mozilla.org/pt-BR/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filtro).

After looking at [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/297673/how-do-i-deal-with-non-english-content) and [How to deal with non-English posts](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/262014/how-to-deal-with-non-english-posts)

I can find no reference to links in this case.

For example [Lucas has posted a good](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39978121/1592783) answer in English however has linked to a Portuguese source. (Granted this was likely by accident and for this site in particular it is trivial to switch languages).

However my question is:

**Is it worth an edit to update the source to directly point to the English source if one exists?**

Comment: Good find pep, sorry i didn't find it in my original search.

Answer (score 7):

In cases like the one you quote I'd be tempted to **add** the link to the English content rather than simply replace it.

If the original page linked to wasn't English and has been translated, then leaving the original link allows people to translate it themselves and verify that the English translation is accurate.