# What to do about a declined flag that was clearly valid before the OP updated their post?

Tags: discussion, feature-request, flags, declined-flags, disputed-flags

There was a post on SO that was all written in what I think is Portuguese.

In the past I have tried to translate and update the post but someone rolled back my edit and said I should not translate and that was fine. I knew then I should just flag any further post like that to be moved. So when I came across this post I flagged it for moderator review saying "This question needs to be move to the correct stack site. SO is English only.".

From my understanding of the flag system my chose was correct and valid but It got declined.

> [image]

I guess the OP must have updated their post to be in English just after I flagged it because the timestamp for their last update is the same as my flag. That said I am assuming this is the reason my flag was declined. The post had been changed by the time the moderator reviewed it.

I do not like to have declined counts on my flag list as I know if one gets too many declined flags they can be flag-banned.

So my concern is how can one go about getting that decline removed as the flag was valid prior to the post being updated?

If no method correctly exist would it be a good idea to add a way to dispute declined flags? Or at least have it removed due to the circumstance?

Maybe add a new declined reason for moderators to select. Something like: "This flag is no longer valid so it is now void". Thus not adding to your declined count.

Original post at the time I flagged it:

> [image]

Comment: Rule #1, #2 and #3 of migrating questions: don't migrate crap.  The decline message is boilerplate.

Comment: @HansPassant How would I know if it is crap. I only speak English.

Comment: Also I could have sworn I posted this on meta...

Comment: If you don't know then you can leave it up to a moderator to make the call.  They did.

Comment: @HansPassant they made the call after the post was updated to English. That is why I am trying to figure out what to to about the declined flag as I flagged it before it was updated.

Comment: You did post this on Meta.

Comment: @CodyGray oh lol I didnt see the meta in the logo. Just the Stack Overflow part of the logo.. This site looks like SO and not Meta so I got confused..

Comment: moderators generally check previous revisions before declining flags. It didn't happen for you, bummer. But no big deal if it happens only once in a while

Comment: @yivi My 1st sentence did not need to be revised. It is grammatically correct. Also the tag `feature request` is also valid as I did ask if a feature might be added for disputing declined flags.

Comment: Sorry it bothered you. It wasn't my intention. I was just tried to make it easier to understand (in my personal opinion), but it's of course your post and you know best. I don't see a "feature" being requested in your question, but keep the tag if you want.

Comment: @yivi "would it be a good idea to add a way to dispute declined flags". It does not bother me I just don't see the point in changing it as the sentence is accurate. I kept the other edit you made.

Comment: On the point about whether the question should be moved so that the person asking gets an answer: It would be possible to post a comment pointing the user to the site with the correct language - let them take care of posting it where it ought to be.

Comment: @CindyMeister I have done that in the past. I thought it would just be a simple matter to flag for migration and move on but I am learning that the rules for migration are somewhat strict so I will just not flat for that anymore.

Comment: A flag ban requires >10 flags in the past week, >25% of which have been declined, and can last a maximum of a week  So unless you've only just started and your 41 flags on main are from the last month or so you're well below the danger threshold.  https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/173878/allow-recovery-from-flag-hellban/175405#175405

Comment: @DanisFiddlingbyFirelight good to know. Thanks for the details.

Comment: 99% of migration requests are rejected.

Comment: rule #4 not mentioned by @HansPassant - if you don't understand the question, assume it's crap (and therefore, don't migrate)

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Please read the flag decline message carefully. It isn't saying that your reasoning is invalid, or that the question didn't need to be closed. It's nitpicking about the type of flag you chose to raise.

You flagged the question using a custom moderator flag. That isn't necessary, and makes it difficult for moderators to prioritize issues, since all custom flags get dumped into the same queue, with no sorting of any kind. A *lot* of disparate issues get raised as custom flags, which makes handling them very time-consuming.

Instead, you should have just voted to close the question. (For users that don't have [close-vote privileges](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/close-questions), you would flag the question as needing to be closed.) For questions in a language other than English, either the "unclear" or "off-topic" reasons are customary. (For "off-topic", you can type in a custom close reason, like "This question is off-topic because it is not written in English. Stack Overflow requires all posts to be in English.")

If possible, a "very low quality" flag would also be warranted in situations like this. At least, in my personal opinion. The moderator who declined your flag is a bit less likely to indulge VLQ flags on questions than I am, so who knows. ;-)

Comment: I have read other meta post where the accepted answer said to use the "other reason" option. That is why I use it. I figured its better to migrate it than to just close it simply because I don't know what it said. Let the correct SO site review it in their own language.

Comment: Ah, yeah. UI confusion. There are two different "other" options. One is under close -> off-topic because... -> other. The other is under flag -> in need of moderator intervention.

Comment: Ah... Ok well I will keep that in mind then. I thought it was nicer to migrate and let the other site decide on its value.

Comment: @Mike That's a separate point, but also an important one to address. Yivi has tried to cover it in his answer. You yourself admitted you have no way of knowing if the question is good, because you can't read/understand it. Well, put yourself in the mod's position: we can't, either. So we don't want to be the ones who risk migrating a bad question that we couldn't read/understand to another site. Other sites don't want to be SO's garbage dumps. As was pointed out in the comments, the crass but nevertheless golden rule of migration is "don't migrate crap". If you can't understand it, it's crap.

Comment: Therefore, in the case of questions not written in English, better to close as "unclear" or "off-topic", rather than to migrate.

Comment: Well if it is up to change if a mod can read the language then migrations for language should probably have their own tag. I think that is a flaw in the way this kind of flag is handled. All depends on if the mod can read the language whether or not it gets moved to the correct stack site... Seams kinda of arbitrary.

Comment: I have accepted your answer in the context of my situation. I still would like to see a way to dispute declined flags or a way of declining a flag that does not result in a declined count on ones profile. My example may not have been as valid as I thought at first (due to their post being "crap" :D ) however the concept of the situation can still apply to other flags.

Comment: @Mike-SMT If there's an appropriate non-english SO you can do some basic sanity checking, ie does it have a reasonable looking code sample, and does google translate offer something that is at least half-way decent for the question text; and then go to the other sites chat and ask if the question's OK.  If you get a positive response there, than that information can be used to justify migration on SO.  If that sounds like too much work, just close and move on.

Answer (score 5):

The *"we don't migrate crap"* rule is better understood as *"we only migrate **good** questions"*.

So, if we are not in a position to discern if a question is good or not, we don't migrate it at all.

In a comment you said:

> How would I know if it is crap. I only speak English.

Same thing could have happened to the mod. And if they aren't sure the question is a good fit for the target site, the reasonable thing is not to migrate, and thus decline the flag.

And since you didn't know the question was good enough, the flag shouldn't have been raised at all.

Comment: Well even with that being the case I the main question of my post is still "What can be done about a flag that is declined even though it was valid at the time the flag was submitted?". My specific issue aside this kind of issue does come op on flags. So is there anything one can do to keep the declined count down so you don't get flag-banned?

Comment: But your flag was not valid at the time it was raised. Maybe you want to look for a valid example to better describe the issue, otherwise the question lends itself to confusion, in my opinion.

Comment: Any flag that is declined after a post was edited fixing the reason it was flag. Be it language or any other reason for flagging. If the OP or someone else edits the post fixing the issue it was flagged for then your flag becomes invalid. As @Jean-FrançoisFabre pointed out it appears not all mod reviewers check previous revisions before making a decision on the flag. Maybe add a new kind of decline that does not add a count to ones decline count. Like this flag is no longer valid so it is void.

Comment: I know. But the specific example you picked, sadly, doesn't fit the case. A moderator that reviewed the history of the post would have had reason to decline as well. So by using an invalid example you distract from point you want to make.

Comment: At the time of posting I thought my reason was valid. Knowing now after answers have been posted that this situation may not be strictly valid in my case doesn't change the core of the question.

Comment: Of course you thought it was valid to raise the flag. I imagine the vast majority of declined flags are raised in good faith, because the flagger believes they are raising the correct flag. But you were wrong, it was not a valid flag. And as using a wrong example to illustrate your question, you distract and confuse from your "core" question. As demonstrated by the two answers you got. Bot are dealing with the specific flag and the decline reason, and not with the feature you appear to want to discuss.

Comment: Well seeing that this was the only flag I have made that I felt this situation applied then I cannot provide another example. I have seen enough over the past 2 years to be sure there are many more flags that fall into this kind of situation but I cannot produce another one. So I guess this post must die :D

Answer (score 0):

**The Declined Flag.**
As [already mentioned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394209/8239061), the flag was declined because it was using a custom mod flag rather than the standard flag(s) for this situation. For more details, see the [Meta canonical](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/297680/8239061) on this which states,

> It is *not recommended* to raise a custom flag to ask a ♦ moderator to
>   migrate these questions to other sites. The odds that migration will
>   happen are extremely low and such flags are usually declined...

**What to do next time:**
Use these two key references the next time you encounter this non-English content:

1. [How do I deal with non-English content?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/297673/8239061), and
2. [How to deal with non-English posts?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/262014/8239061).

**Concern over Flag Ban.** As pointed out in the comments, a  [flag ban](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/175405/476162)

> requires >10 flags in the past week, >25% of which have been declined, and can last a maximum of a week. ([comment](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/394207/what-to-do-about-a-declined-flag-that-was-clearly-valid-before-the-op-updated-th/394227#comment757209_394207) by @[Dan is Fiddling by Firelight](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/users/85661/dan-is-fiddling-by-firelight)).

<sub>Can turn this answer into community wiki if that's more appropriate.</sub>