# Would someone leave a helpful comment on this migrated question that was rejected?

Tags: support, closed-questions, migrated-questions

I’m a moderator on Ask Different and migrated what we consider to be a code level question to Stack Overflow. That migration was rejected without any sort of comment.

The OP is confused and I’d rather not tell them to re-post the question on SO as it could be fixed and reopened IMO if someone here could lend a hand…

- [Requesting visual style in an implementation that has disabled it - Xcode 15 iOS 17](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77354622/requesting-visual-style-in-an-implementation-that-has-disabled-it-xcode-15-ios)

It’s totally lacking MCVE and appears to be a compiler / runtime error message so it should be on topic here with enough detail..

Would someone review this and comment on that post or edit it / answer here such that there’s some clue what needs to be fixed?

Comment: cross-posted here: https://developer.apple.com/forums/thread/740224

Comment: "It’s totally lacking MCVE" and you're wondering why migration was rejected!?! First rule of migration is: [you don't migrate crap](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/394208/215552)!

Comment: That’s not the first rule of migration since a mod on one site doesn’t have to be an expert in another. It might only need three lines of code to explain exactly how to reproduce the error message and the OP clearly is a seasoned developer and the error is totally undocumented, so those items weighed in on my decision to migrate and not just tell them to pack sand… I still recall shog’s advice to not be so precious about migrations. Just do it. The system can work it out as shown here..

Comment: The post does not ask 1 (specific researched non-duplicate) question (besides the lack of MRE) & the questions it asks are rhetorical yes-or-no & this-or-that that seem extremely likely not what the asker actually want an answer to. It's a rambling narrative social stream-of-consciousness. I don't know how this can't be apparent. Especially to a moderator.

Comment: @bmike While they don't need to be an expert on the target site, if you're not pretty familiar with the rules/scope of the target site, it can be good to ping either a (diamond) moderator of the target site or an experienced user that's familiar with the scope of the target site in chat so they can give you a suggestion on migration. Also, that is the _golden_ rule of migration. Specifically, I'd suggest reading [this MSE answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/91446) by Jeff Atwood.

Answer (score 14, accepted):

The point of migration is to move a question to a different site in the community where it would both be on-topic *and* meet the site's guidelines. The post you've linked, at a minimum, doesn't fulfil that second requirement and you admit that it lacks a minimal reproducible example. As a result the question was closed per Stack Overflow's guidelines, as it required debugging details.

There is, however, a difference to the behaviour when a migrated question is closed, it is returned to the original site it was closed on. This means that the question *cannot* be a candidate for reopening (even as a user with ~90k reputation there is no reopen option). The question will likely remain closed on the other site as well, if it isn't on-topic (which it appears it isn't as as a moderator you closed it).

The correct action here would been to vote to close the question (on Ask Different), however, note in the comments that the question would likely be on topic on a different site in the community, such as Stack Overflow. As you are aware that the question doesn't meet the guidelines though, you should tell them that as well. Link them to the site's [tour](//stackoverflow.com/tour), and if you know what *might* improve it, advise them of that.

If the OP then chooses to cross-post and not improve the question then it would be closed again, for the same reason, but it could be improved and reopened. Though, they could likely have to wait *days* for the question to get successfully through the reopen queue.

Of course, if you encounter a question you know would fit the site well, do migrate it. In truth, Migrating is *hard*; there are many questions that get rejected by the site the question is sent to. Unfortunately, as curators, we aren't always aware of the nuances of other sites, and that can mean that a question that *looks* good still might not "ok" on the other site.

Comment: Thank you so much. This will help the OP know how to proceed and I appreciate the eyes on this.