# How to flag non-English answers

Tags: discussion, answers, flags, close-reasons, english

I know and understand that there are many people that know more than one language. But I found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29592661/1380867), and it is in Spanish. I know Spanish, and it's a good answer, but it is in the wrong language.

How should I flag it?

Comment: Related: [How does StackOverflow avoid questions that are not in English?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251725). In this case, flag as  low-quality.

Comment: Translate it ? ​

Comment: I'd flag it as "not an Answer". Stack Overflow (this version of it, at least), is English. Since the question is Spanish as well... well, yes.

Comment: The question is already closed, so there is not much point in flagging the answer as well now.

Comment: Ok, I translated it. Hope the reviewers will approve it..

Comment: @JonasCz: did you also do that for the *question*? The post is closed as off-topic because the question is *also* in Spanish. There is no point in fixing the answer at this point in time.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, Yes, I did.

Comment: @JonasCz translating it is just about the worst thing you can do. If OP asks in spanish, that's a big indication they don't speak english, so translating "for them" does not do them a service, and it doesn't help the community as well, because OP cannot be expected to react to any english comments or answers. If the question itself were worthwile and not a duplicate, it could be re-asked in a translated version by an OP who actually speaks english. In this case however, the question seems like it's crap and should be deleted, not edited.

Comment: @JonasCz: I agree with l4mpi here; the question is *I want to use a query like this*, so even translated it is a crap question and should just remain closed. There is no value to be recovered here.

Comment: @MartijnPieters, l4mpi, Okay.

Comment: Seems like it was removed.

Comment: Though the answer was in Spanish, the question seems to have been in Portuguese. It would perhaps have been helpful to point the OP to the Portuguese Stack Overflow site.

Comment: @legoscia: the question quality was very, very low. It was basically a gimme-the-codez post asking someone to translate a SQL query to Ruby-on-Rails ORM syntax. I'm not sure redirecting the user to PT.SO would have been all that helpful.

Comment: @l4mpi - I think the 'correct' way to translate the content is to retain the original text above or below the translation, so that people can benefit from it regardless of which language they speak.  Next to that, deleting content that's in one language and then reposting it in another that the OP does not understand is not a better option.  That does _nothing whatsoever_ to help the OP.  Seriously, you might as well scream "learn English" at them in ALLCAPS for all the good deleting/reposting their content in English will do.

Comment: @aroth well, _we don't care at all about helping the OP_. This site does not exist to help idividual posters, it exists to build a knowledge repository, and it has the rule that all content must be in English. If somebody cannot speak English, they simply cannot participate on SO. If a non-English post ends up on SO that would make a genuinely useful question, then its usefulness should be preserved for all other potential readers. If OP cannot read it, too bad, but that's not something we should concern ourselves with.

Comment: @l4mpi - Speak for yourself.  The _only_ reason I spend time on SO is to give and occasionally receive help.  At least some of us don't care at all about the overarching _building a knowledge repository_ thing (Google does that, regardless).  I think the hubris around that, and the ever-increasing willingness to forcibly exclude anything that doesn't play to that end, will be significant problems one day.  SO didn't get to where it is because it set out with a single-minded purpose of building a knowledge-base.  It got there by providing a reliable place _for individuals_ to come and get help.

Comment: @aroth "It got there by providing a reliable place for individuals to come and get help" - and it only got to be reliable in the first place due to the high quality standards and their enforcement; not due to being just another site where you "get help" (there's tons of them, most suck). Also, the ever-increasing willingness by parts of the community to ignore those standards in the name of "helping" (mostly "spoon feeding") individuals who fail to meet those standards causes problems _right now_, turning this from a site for professionals and enthusiasts into everybodys online debugger.

Comment: @l4mpi - IMO the key factors in SO's success were 1) users voting on content, 2) persistent reputation scores for each user, and 3) increasing (and tangible) rewards for attaining higher rep scores.  In essence, SO gamified Q&A, making it both useful and fun.  _That_ was the breakthrough.  I don't think high standards, "proactive" moderation, or the removal of useful content due to technicalities factor into that much.  There are many bad Q&A sites (some even moderated more than SO), and there are also some newer ones that basically copy SO's UX and are much improved because of it.

Answer (score 15, accepted):

Flag it as not an answer. Do not add a translation. This site is in English only.

Comment: Is just translating better? That would make it an answer, right?

Comment: @PatrickHofman if the OP asked the question in Spanish on an English site, there is a **lot** of chances he can't read English so translation won't help him

Comment: It was regarding an answer, not a question.

Comment: @PatrickHofman : I know the question is about translating the answer, but if the OP can't read the answer, translation is useless (for him) and if he can read English, then he should have posted in English...

Comment: That's silly.  We've got people willing and able to perform the translation, and vouching for the quality of the answer.  There's no reason to discard useful information because of some "this site is in English only" dogma.  It makes far more sense to translate it _while also retaining the original text_ above or below the translation.  Then it can be up to the developers to come up with a more clever way of presenting multilingual content, when available, based upon the browser's locale settings.

Comment: @Patrick and aroth: assuming OP does not speak English (otherwise they should simply ask in English), there are two cases: either the question is bad, meaning nobody cares if it is answered or not, and it should just be deleted. Or, the question is useful (to more people than just OP), then someone should re-ask it in English, _not_ translate it; because leaving OP with a post he owns but no longer understands just leads to problems. If the question already attracted a non-English answer which is useful, then this should be translated and added to the other post as well.

Comment: And of course, if the answerer is capable of writing in English, then one should ask them to answer the cloned question in English, and only add a translated version of their answer (with proper attribution of course) if they fail to do so.

Comment: @l4mpi - We'll just have to disagree.  Leaving the OP with their original question abandoned and a new one posted in English by someone else does them no favors, in my opinion (they're not going to find the new post, and even if they do, they won't be able to read it).  As noted, I said the translation should retain the original text at all times, so that the OP and others can _both_ understand it.

Comment: @aroth as I just replied to your comment on the question, SOs goal is not to do _OP_ a favour, it's to create an _English_ knowledge repository. This simply excludes people who don't speak English, period.

Comment: @aroth: It's official SE policy that the english SO site is in english. Only under very restricted circumstances a solitary ephemeral non-english comment is allowed for clarification. Please respect it.

Comment: @Deduplicator - I do respect it, by posting my own content in English.  Helping someone who's unable to post _their_ content in English also respects it (assuming you provide a translation), and at the same time respects the non-English speaker by judging their content on its merits as opposed to its packaging.  Besides, "it's the policy" is not a good rationale, particularly in cases where the policy is exclusionary to large segments of the population.

Answer (score 6):

### Translation to English is often best

#### ... but not always, and by no means an obligation

Appropriate action for a non-English question:

- In the spirit of keeping useful information, **translate** to English if you can AND feel so inclined AND the post is worth it (which it wasn't, in this specific case, mind you). Remove the original language content.
- Else, close as off-topic, custom reason.

Appropriate action for a non-English answer: basically the same:

- In the spirit of keeping useful information, **translate** to English if you can AND feel so inclined AND the post is worth it. Remove the original language content.
- Else, flag as not an answer.

### Assume by default that the OP and future readers can read English

Many comments here assert that:

1. if someone *wrote* a post in non-English, then there's a very high likelihood that they can't *read* English,
2. and therefore *it isn't worth translating the post*.

**This is fallacious and should be dismissed on both counts**:

1. Anyone who (like me) has gone through the process of learning one or more new languages in their life will tell you that you pick up the reading part much, *much* more quickly than the writing part. There are millions of people out there who can read English adequately but are not yet capable of expressing themselves clearly with the written Shakespearean word. Unless there is specific evidence to the contrary, there is no good reason to assume these people away. The OP did, after all, correctly read the "Ask Question" and "Post Your Answer" buttons! *
2. The post doesn't just serve the OP, it serves everyone else who will ever read it. In English.

Let it therefore be concluded that a good translated post is better than a deleted one. Though again, only if it was worth it in the first place.

<sub>*This is by no means a moral defence of the person who chose to write a non-English post on an English-only site; doing that is plain silly. But the issue isn't about the person; it's about what to do with the material.</sub>

Comment: _Your_ fallacy is that you don't take into account that the people against translation via hostile edit are not agains _reposting_ a translated version. Let's say you're right and OP can read but not write English, then they cannot reasonably respond to English comments or answers - which is in turn a loss for everybody else interacting with the question or answer. I'm all for translating useful posts, but if the poster cannot speak English, then the English content should be posted by somebody who does speak the language.

Comment: @l4mpi: I'm making an argument for what should be done with the existing material — not what the OP should or shouldn't have done (because regarding that, sure, I agree). Not sure why you consider translation a "hostile" edit. Nothing hostile about it. If I understand correctly, you're saying that if we translate, then post that in a new question rather than as an edit? Okay, honestly I don't see the point (because that's not how we salvage other questions), or why one would feel strongly for the former over the latter, but whatever works for you.

Comment: Translating becomes a hostile edit when it conflicts with the authors intent, which is extremely probable given they originally posted in a different language. You simply cannot guarantee that your translation doesn't get rolled back or deleted or that OP simply abandons the post (which is the least bad scenario, but still worse than having an OP who cares about the question). All of these problems are nonexistent when simply reposting the translation.

Comment: I can never guarantee that any of my edits won't get rolled back; in fact, they sometimes *do* get rolled back. No big deal. I still do them, though, in cases where I judge it will make the site better. Same here. The author's intent is, quite frankly, something you and I only can speculate about; not a particularly productive activity, in my opinion. You argue that the user's intent is to intentionally post a non-English question; I argue that I don't know and don't care. P.S. No, I won't start a "rollback war". It's only a war if you make it one.

Comment: You _can_ guarantee that nobody can roll back anything, by simply reposting the question in English. And no, you wouldn't have to start a rollback war, but you would otherwise have to closevote and vote to delete the post if it's rolled back, thereby wasting everybodys time. And I don't care about the authors intent either, but I doubt that anybody who misses the fact that the site is only for English posts can provide a high-quality question in the first place. Anyways, why do _you_ think it's important to preserve the original question? Why not delete the original and repost a translation?

Comment: Why not? Because we don't do that for any other kind of edit, even massive clarification and formatting. To me, a translation is equivalent to formatting. As for reposting to pre-empt some future hypothetical rollback -- well, you could say that about any other edit, too; and it sounds far-fetched. But please, do enlighten me by pointing me to all those awful rollback wars that are raging on translated posts all around SO.

Comment: "To me, a translation is equivalent to formatting" - uh, what? Sorry, that makes absolutely no sense. And when we're at it, please point me to just one single high-quality post that was written in a different language than English and then translated by somebody else than the original author.

Comment: Okay, that's fine, just focus on the rest of my comment, then. That was just a remark on how I personally perceive such an edit; you don't have to agree at all. Also, I haven't argued that there are many high-quality non-English posts, so I feel no need or obligation to substantiate that straw man claim.

Comment: Calling me out on a "straw man claim" that was a direct response to yours doesn't exactly help your point. But your remark is IMO exactly the problem here - if you perceive a translation as analoguous to formatting, your stance becomes understandable. But it's far from the same.

Comment: You've argued that translation edits can lead to rollback wars. I asked for substantiating evidence. Then you asked for evidence supporting a claim I didn't make. I'm not calling "you" out; I'm refusing to defend a position that I don't hold a.k.a. a straw man.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/75195/discussion-between-jean-francois-corbett-and-l4mpi). [Automatically generated comment.]

Comment: "You've argued that translation edits can lead to rollback wars" - note the word _can_. Seriously, we have rollback wars over minor formatting edits, and you think we won't have any about translating a post, which is a major change? And you argue that one should translate a post via edit, which for me means it _can_ lead to good content (why else would you recommend it?), which is what I asked you to prove to show how absurd your claim for proof was. And btw, if there were any rollback wars over translations the posts in question would quickly be deleted anyways.

Comment: Did you consider that moderation of your edit completely falls apart, as one has to be proficient in the topic of the post and the source-language, in addition to english, just to have a chance to catch any errors?

Comment: @Deduplicator: No, I had not. Good point. That's the first good argument against translating I've read in this entire thread. Though I'd say, you're probably overstating the difficulty a little bit, because an automated translator will usually allow an edit moderator to understand the question. But you're right, it is a hindrance.