# Would you flag an answer answered in language different to the question?

Tags: discussion, flags

I was doing some reviews and I came across a question answered in Arabic, Would you flag the answer if the question was asked in English? if so, what flag is relevant in this case?

**Update**: Related question 
 
[How does Stack Overflow avoid questions that are not in English?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/251725/how-does-stackoverflow-avoid-questions-that-are-not-in-english)

Comment: I would flag the answer if the question was in English, and flag the question if both were in arabic, as Stack is purely English (for now)

Comment: And i'd flag it as Unclear What you're Asking /  NAA for answers.

Comment: Related: [How does StackOverflow avoid questions that are not in English?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/251725)

Comment: depends. If it included code and i knew that the code snippet included answered the question, i'd downvote and leave a comment asking for it to be translated to english. Unless another answer existed that was already in english with the same solution.

Comment: thanks guys, the duplicate and relevant question have answered my question. do i remove or stay put?

Comment: Just leave it.  The question has slightly different wording, so anyone looking for this particular question would have a better chance of finding at least one of the three (currently).